# ajax is not updating a component situated in another <ui:define

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

Hi i have a command link so when click it i `action="#{projectAdminisrationMB.showGroups(userObj)}"` a fieldset will be rendred `<p:fieldset legend="Manage User Groups" id="manageUserGroupsFS" rendered="#{projectAdminisrationMB.manageUserGroupsFSFlag}">`
when the fieldset was in the same `<ui:define name="body">` everything works but when i put it in a separated ui:define  it will not be rendered.

Here's the code :

```
<ui:define name="body">

         <h:form id="manageProjeUFform">  

            <div class="right">

             <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />  

             <br/><br/><br/><br/>

<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  

   <p:column>
            <p:fieldset legend=" Users ">  
               <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  

             <p:dataTable border="1" value="#{projectAdminisrationMB.projectUsersList}"
                    id="projectUserDt" 
                    var="userObj"
                    rowKey="#{userObj.name}"
                     selection="#{projectAdminisrationMB.selectedExistingProjectUser}"
                     selectionMode="single"
                     rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
                      binding="#{table1}">
                        <p:column id="column1">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Login"></h:outputText>
                            </f:facet>


                           <h:outputText value="#{userObj.name}"/>  


                        </p:column>
                        <p:column id="column2">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Entire Name"></h:outputText>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{userObj.lastName}"></h:outputText>



                            <h:outputText value="#{userObj.firstName}"></h:outputText>
                         </p:column>


                                <p:column id="column5">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Groups"></h:outputText>
                            </f:facet>

                             <p:commandLink id="manageUG"  title="Manage User Groups" style="margin-right:5px"  update=":rightContentform:manageUserGroupsFS"   action="#{projectAdminisrationMB.showGroups(userObj)}"  ajax="true"> 
                                   <h:graphicImage value="../images/cssImg/manage-groups-icon.png"   />

                                 <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{projectAdminisrationMB.selectedUserRow}" value="#{userObj}" />
                                 <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{projectAdminisrationMB.selectedUserRow.dbRowIndex}" value="#{table.rowIndex}" />

                            </p:commandLink>   



                         </p:column>

                         <f:facet name="footer">  


                  <p:commandButton id="addProjectUserdlg" value=" Add " onclick="dlg1.show()"  />  
                  <p:commandButton id="deleteProjectUserdlg" value=" Delete "  onclick="confirmation.show()"/>  

                          </f:facet> 

                </p:dataTable>
```

```
               </h:panelGrid>  
             </p:fieldset>  

        </div>

         </h:form>
     </ui:define>
```

```
   <h:panelGrid columns="3">
    <h:panelGrid id="display" header="User Detail" columns="2" cellpadding="4">  

                           <f:facet name="header">  
                             <p:graphicImage value="/images/users/user.png"/>  
                          </f:facet>   

                            <h:outputText value="Login:" />  
                            <h:outputText value="#{projectAdminisrationMB.selectedUserRow.lastName}" />  

                            <h:outputText value="Name:" />  
                            <h:outputText value="#{projectAdminisrationMB.selectedUserRow.lastName}" />  

                            <h:outputText value="First Name:" />  
                            <h:outputText value="#{projectAdminisrationMB.selectedUserRow.firstName}" />  

                            <h:outputText value="Email:" />  
                            <h:outputText value="#{projectAdminisrationMB.selectedUserRow.email}" />  

                            <h:outputText value="Phone:" />  
                            <h:outputText value="#{projectAdminisrationMB.selectedUserRow.phoneNumber}" />  

                      </h:panelGrid>  

           <p:pickList id="pickList" value="#{projectAdminisrationMB.selectedUserGroups}" var="group"   
            itemLabel="#{group}" itemValue="#{group}" converter="groupConverter" > 

             <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Belong To</f:facet>  
             <f:facet name="targetCaption">Exclude From</f:facet> 

              <p:column style="width:25%">  
                    <p:graphicImage value="/images/group/#{group.name}.gif" />  
               </p:column>  

             <p:column style="width:75%;">  
                  #{group.name}  
             </p:column> 
              <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{projectAdminisrationMB.onTransferGroup}" update=":manageProjeUFform:growl" />  
             </p:pickList>

             <p:commandButton id="saveGroupsBtn" value="Save"  update=":manageProjeUFform:growl" actionListener="#{projectAdminisrationMB.saveUserGroupsModif}"/>  



          </h:panelGrid>
  </p:fieldset>
</h:form>
  </ui:define>
```

Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: Apparently, it's a template issue  ,in other words you can't update a component from another 'ui:define' with ajax (we have the same problem)

Comment: the most important parts are invisible, the indentation is wrong, `pickList`, `<br/><br/><br/><br/>` are irrelevant, etc. etc. could you improve your question?

Comment: That's pretty a lot of code noise. Are for example the `<div class="right">`, `style="width:25%"` and `<h:outputText value="Login:" />` absolutely necessary in order for us to reproduce your concrete problem by copy'n'paste'n'running the given code? No? Just omit them. This way the problem in the code can quicker be spotted by just looking at the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the solution enjoy it :)

```
<p:commandLink id="manageUG"  title="Manage User Groups" style="margin-right:5px"  
 update="@all"   action="#{projectAdminisrationMB.showGroups(userObj)}"  ajax="true"> 
                                   <h:graphicImage value="../images/cssImg/manage-groups-icon.png"   />

                                 <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{projectAdminisrationMB.selectedUserRow}" value="#{userObj}" />
                                 <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{projectAdminisrationMB.selectedUserRow.dbRowIndex}" value="#{table.rowIndex}" />

                            </p:commandLink>
```

i used @all to update the ui define section that's it

Comment: It'd be helpful if you explain in detail what exactly you've changed. This is really invisible in this code noise. Is it the link ID attriubute? Is it the link title attriubute? Is it the link style attriubute? Is it the link update attriubute? Is it the link ajax attriubute? Etc.