# Unable to update elements in different ui:define

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm working with a template that has ui:insert tags.
In the page I define (ui:define) two of them (content, rightSide).
I have an event on rowSelect so that one row's detail is shown in the rightSide.
So far I haven't been able to update the rightSideDiv via ajax.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
   template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">

        <p:dataTable id="clasifTable" var="clasif" value="#{clasificacionController.clasificaciones}"
            rows="10" sortMode="multiple" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{clasif.idClasificacion}">
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{clasificacionController.onClasificacionSelect}" update="rightSideDiv" />

            <p:column headerText="Id" sortBy="#{clasif.idClasificacion}">
                <h:outputText value="#{clasif.idClasificacion}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Descripción" sortBy="#{clasif.descripcion}">
                <h:outputText value="#{clasif.descripcion}" />
            </p:column>

            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="rightSide">
        <div id="rightSideDiv">
            <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:outputLabel for="idClasificacionText" value="id:" />
                <p:inputText id="idClasificacionText" value="#{clasificacion.idClasificacion}"/>
                <p:outputLabel for="descripcionText" value="Descripción:"/>
                <p:inputText id="descripcionText" value="#{clasificacion.descripcion}"/>
                <p:outputLabel for="detalleText" value="Detalle:"/>
                <p:inputText id="detalleText" value="#{clasificacion.detalle}"/>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </div>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

This post, suggesting using `update="@all"` is the only workaround that I coud find

[ajax is not updating a component situated in another <ui:define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296268/ajax-is-not-updating-a-component-situated-in-another-uidefine)

But obviously this is not ideal since the whole page gets rerendered. Also the post is from 2012, so I was hoping there's something new about this.

I'm using primefaces 6.0 and jsf 2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to update HTML element. Replace `<div id="rightSideDiv">` with JSF component `<h:panelGroup id="rightSideDiv" layout="block">` and it should work.